# Почему ошибка Object of type 'Product' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, сериализация

Кусок с функции, как я пытаюсь использовать обьект модели.

```python
request.session['basket'][str(product_id)] = {'product': Product.objects.get(pk=product_id),
                                                          'amount': int(request.POST.get('amount'))}
```

Собственно сама модель:

```js
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Категория')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Название',
                             validators=[validators.MinLengthValidator(3)])
    amount = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество на складе', validators=[validators.MinValueValidator(5)])
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описание',
                                   validators=[validators.MinLengthValidator(10)])
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Изображение', upload_to=icon_upload_path)
    price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Цена', validators=[validators.MinValueValidator(0)])
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата создания')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Дата обновления')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Товары'
        verbose_name = 'Товар'
        ordering = ['-created_at']
```

Answer (score 2):

Как и сказано, объект `Product` не может быть сериализирован. 
Чтобы решить проблему, преобразуейте объект в словарь, либо вручную, либо через `model_to_dict`, либо используйте Django REST API.

Так же можете заглянуть в [документацию по сериализации данных](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/serialization/). Так есть еще способы решения данной проблемы